# transforming XML with XSLT gives a wrong result

Tags: python, xml, xslt, lxml

I want to transform a two item XML to a two line piece of HTML

```
from lxml import etree


xroot = etree.XML(b'''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xml>
        <name>donald</name>
        <surname>trump</surname>
    </xml>
    ''')
xml=etree.ElementTree(xroot)
xslt_root = etree.XML('''
     <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
         xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
         <xsl:template match="xml">
             <div id='name'><xsl:value-of select="name" /></div>
             <div id='surname'><xsl:value-of select="surname" /></div>
         </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>''')
transform = etree.XSLT(xslt_root)
transform=etree.XSLT(xslt_root)
html=etree.tostring(transform(xml)).decode('utf-8')
print(html)
```

The result that I expect is:

```
 <div id='name'>donald</div>
 <div id='surname'>trump</div>
```

But the result I get is:

```
 <div id='name'>donald</div>
```

Why??

Comment: The problem is not with your XSLT: http://xsltransform.net/gVAjbSS

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i'm not exactly aware of the reason, but what about doing this

```
from lxml import etree

xroot = etree.XML(b'''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xml>
        <name>donald</name>
        <surname>trump</surname>
    </xml>
    ''')
xml = etree.ElementTree(xroot)
xslt_root = etree.XML('''
     <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
         xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
         <xsl:template match="xml">
             <div id='name'><xsl:value-of select="name" /></div>
             <div id='surname'><xsl:value-of select="surname" /></div>
         </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>''')
# transform = etree.XSLT(xslt_root)
transform = etree.XSLT(xslt_root)
# html = etree.tostring(transform(xml)).decode('utf-8')
# print(html)
print(str(transform(xml)).split('\n'))
# ['<?xml version="1.0"?>', '<div id="name">donald</div><div id="surname">trump</div>', '']
# the element at index 1 contains <div id="name">donald</div><div id="surname">trump</div>
```

Comment: That's really a bad solution. Removing the preamble is done by using xsl:output/@omit-xml-declaration, not with string operations. Especially because any newline in the actual body of the document might prematurely split it in more than one array element.

Comment: @AlexanderGräf I clearly said that I'm not aware of the reason and that's not an ideal solution but it works for that particular scenario. can you provide a better solution? i'll be happy to upvote it.

Comment: @YassineAddi I wrote it; provide an xsl:output tag as the first element before xsl:template, with the attribute omit-xml-declaration="yes". This will suppress emitting the initial <?xml ... ?> and no further string splitting is required. The output isn't a valid XML document anyway, so the preamble is wrong.

Comment: @AlexanderGräf got it, thanks for taking the time to explain.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably because the result of your transformation is not [well-formed XML](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-well-formed) (because you don't have a single root element; you have two `div` elements).

Passing the not well-formed XML to `tostring()`, which expects an element (singular) or tree, appears to be the reason you're only seeing the first result element.

If you wrap the `div`s in a single element (like `test`), you'll see both `div`s...

```py
from lxml import etree

xroot = etree.XML(b'''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xml>
        <name>donald</name>
        <surname>trump</surname>
    </xml>
    ''')
xml = etree.ElementTree(xroot)
xslt_root = etree.XML('''
     <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
         xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
         <xsl:template match="xml">
             <test>
                 <div id='name'><xsl:value-of select="name" /></div>
                 <div id='surname'><xsl:value-of select="surname" /></div>
             </test>
         </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>''')
transform = etree.XSLT(xslt_root)
html = etree.tostring(transform(xml)).decode('utf-8')
print(html)
```

Print output...

```
<test><div id="name">donald</div><div id="surname">trump</div></test>
```

Just printing the result of the transform (`print(transform(xml))`) also shows both `div`s (with no changes to the XSLT).

Comment: I don't know about Python, but XSLT **can** output an XML fragment.

Comment: @michael.hor257k - Yes, of course, XSLT can output a lot of different formats. The problem isn't with the XSLT; it's most likely the `tostring()` being used on the result from `transform()`.

Comment: @michael.hor257k - I updated my answer a little. Hope this helps clarify.